# Error: Could not find or load main class pirates.App Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pirates.App (scala)

Tags: scala, mxnet

I already added in pom.xml but when run the program it produce error " 
couldn't load main class? 
code: https://github.com/ali2210/Mxnet
reference:
https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/tutorials/scala/mxnet_scala_on_intellij.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have unnecessary `]` in a link to Github (Your link doesn't work).

You need to add `object App extends App` instead of `object App`

or define main method `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { }` inside `App` object

Comment: Thanks i will try

Comment: @AliHassan is it works? If yes please set this question as solved. If no and you need some help please contact me and give more details